# What does this ps command do on Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, command

I try to get the output of the top 5 processes in a Linux system. I'm expecting to get the percentage of processor (CPU) used but I'm a little worried about if the command that I'm using gets the CPU or the RAM; what is the output?

```
ps -A --sort -rss -o comm,pmem | head -n 6
```

The man documentation of `ps` indicates that the output is the process, but I'm suspecting that is the RAM memory.  Could you clarify the output for me, please?

Comment: You seem to be sorting by `rss` but printing command and process memory.  Are you sure that's what you want?  You could show the output you get, too; it's only 6 lines.

Comment: I want only the 5 process that consume more CPU

Comment: Sort by `pcpu` instead then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a process sorting by `rss` which is resident set size - memory usage - and then showing you the command and percentage memory usage. Header line and top 5 processes.

For an explanation of what RSS actually is, see this answer on `unix`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35129/need-explanation-on-resident-set-size-virtual-size

To get the top 5 by CPU load as you asked:

```
ps -A --sort -pcpu -o comm,pmem,pcpu | head -n 6
```

Comment: By memory you mean to RAM?

Comment: Basically, yes. See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35129/need-explanation-on-resident-set-size-virtual-size

Comment: With that command the output is the RAM and the %, just that I need. Thanks. It's anyway to sizeup the precission, instead of 0.0%, 0.0x%?

Comment: I'd have thought probably not within the `ps` command - although you could probably print the raw memory figured with `-o rss` to give the raw numbers. It won't actually sum to the RAM in your system though, so it'll be a bit hit and miss to percentages.